# Dative and akkusative

Tags: dative, accusative, standard-german

How do you say

> Now, do you love me?

in German?

I considered 2 options:

> 1. Jetzt, Iiebe dir mich?
> 2. Jetzt, liebe mir dich?

I think second one is correct. Please help with the underlying grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of them is correct.

1. Conjugation:

> Ich liebe
>
> Du lieb**st**
>
> Er liebt
>
> ...

2. *Now* can't be translated literally. In german, *jetzt* isn't used for everything *now* is used for. I think *also* or *nun* would fit better as translation.
3. You have to use *mich*. **Wen** liebst du? **Mich**. (Akkusative of the personal pronoun)

All put together:

> Also, liebst du mich?
>
> Nun, liebst du mich?

Note: There are propably more translations that would fit.